# number representation change using concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are many questions asking about how to concatenate a string and an integer for example `4` and `"Blue"` to `4Blue`. This can be done by casting the integer as a string `str(4)` and adding it with `"Blue"` (`str(4) + "Blue"`).

*I am trying to convert a number to its three-digit equivalent (Or bearing form). For example, 40 would become 040.*

I have quickly put together this code:

```
number=90
newn = number

one="0"
two="00"
num=str(number)
length=len(num)

if length == 1:
    newn = two + num
elif length == 2:
    newn = one + num
elif length == 3:
    pass

print(newn)
```

Which outputs this, as expected:

```
090
>>>
```

I was wondering what the simplest way of doing this would be, along with if this is a good method of achieving this.

Comment: [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatspec) has a mini language for specifying formating.

Comment: @AChampion Thank you very much, these will be very useful for me.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.6 you can use an "f_string" (aka [_Formatted string literal_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)) which means all you need is a `print(f'{length:03}')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do:

```
print('{:03}'.format(90))
```

You can change the number `3` depending on how many leading zeros you want to have.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am still very new to python. May I ask exactly how the `:03` is used for the format? (This is very badly worded, I apologise.)

Comment: @Cheesecake You should read the official docs that  AChampion has linked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
s = str(num).zfill(3)
print(s)
```

`3` means leading zeros count.